# OutOfBoundsException - Sentry - Jean85\PrettyVersions - Composer update error - Laravel

Tags: laravel, composer-php, sentry

I ran a composer update and get the following error:

```
   OutOfBoundsException  : Package "sentry/sentry" is not installed

  at /home/vagrant/project/churchinterestlist/vendor/composer/InstalledVersions.php:188
    184|
    185|             return $installed['versions'][$packageName]['pretty_version'];
    186|         }
    187|
  > 188|         throw new \OutOfBoundsException('Package "' . $packageName . '" is not installed');
    189|     }
    190|
    191|     /**
    192|      * @param  string      $packageName

  Exception trace:

  1   Composer\InstalledVersions::getPrettyVersion("sentry/sentry")
      /home/vagrant/project/churchinterestlist/vendor/jean85/pretty-package-versions/src/PrettyVersions.php:25

  2   Jean85\PrettyVersions::getVersion("sentry/sentry")
      /home/vagrant/project/churchinterestlist/vendor/sentry/sentry/src/ClientBuilder.php:79
```

The App was working just fine beforehand and nothing has changed other than the running of composer update. I can see the sentry records in both composer.json and the composer.lock files so sentry should be installed just fine. I have been running Sentry just fine on this app for the last couple months.

I checked to see if I needed to upgrade composer but I'm running the latest version so I also tried rolling that back to an earlier version but that did not help. I have also tried rolling back sentry to an earlier version but that also is not the solution. It seems like `Jean85\PrettyVersions` is also involved in the issues but I don't know where to go next.

This is the proceeding action before the error occurs:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 1 install, 28 updates, 0 removals
  - Upgrading alek13/slack (2.1.0 => 2.1.1)
  - Locking aws/aws-crt-php (v1.0.2)
  - Upgrading aws/aws-sdk-php (3.190.5 => 3.192.0)
  - Upgrading composer/composer (2.1.5 => 2.1.6)
  - Upgrading filp/whoops (2.14.0 => 2.14.1)
  - Upgrading laravel/dusk (v6.17.1 => v6.18.0)
  - Upgrading laravel/framework (v6.20.32 => v6.20.33)
  - Upgrading laravel/vapor-cli (v1.24.0 => v1.24.2)
  - Upgrading laravel/vapor-core (v2.12.2 => v2.12.3)
  - Upgrading php-http/message (1.11.2 => 1.12.0)
  - Upgrading phpoption/phpoption (1.7.5 => 1.8.0)
  - Upgrading phpunit/phpunit (8.5.19 => 8.5.20)
  - Upgrading seld/phar-utils (1.1.1 => 1.1.2)
  - Upgrading sendinblue/api-v3-sdk (v7.4.3 => v7.4.4)
  - Upgrading stripe/stripe-php (v7.93.0 => v7.95.0)
  - Upgrading symfony/console (v4.4.29 => v4.4.30)
  - Upgrading symfony/error-handler (v4.4.27 => v4.4.30)
  - Upgrading symfony/event-dispatcher (v4.4.27 => v4.4.30)
  - Upgrading symfony/finder (v4.4.27 => v4.4.30)
  - Upgrading symfony/http-client (v5.3.4 => v5.3.7)
  - Upgrading symfony/http-foundation (v4.4.29 => v4.4.30)
  - Upgrading symfony/http-kernel (v4.4.29 => v4.4.30)
  - Upgrading symfony/intl (v5.3.4 => v5.3.7)
  - Upgrading symfony/mime (v5.3.4 => v5.3.7)
  - Upgrading symfony/options-resolver (v5.3.4 => v5.3.7)
  - Upgrading symfony/process (v4.4.27 => v4.4.30)
  - Upgrading symfony/routing (v4.4.27 => v4.4.30)
  - Upgrading symfony/translation (v4.4.27 => v4.4.30)
  - Upgrading symfony/var-dumper (v4.4.27 => v4.4.30)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 3 updates, 0 removals
  - Downloading alek13/slack (2.1.1)
  - Downloading aws/aws-crt-php (v1.0.2)
  - Downloading aws/aws-sdk-php (3.192.0)
  - Downloading laravel/vapor-cli (v1.24.2)
  - Upgrading alek13/slack (2.1.0 => 2.1.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing aws/aws-crt-php (v1.0.2): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading aws/aws-sdk-php (3.191.9 => 3.192.0): Extracting archive
  - Upgrading laravel/vapor-cli (v1.24.1 => v1.24.2): Extracting archive
Package fzaninotto/faker is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package phpunit/php-token-stream is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package sebastian/resource-operations is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating optimized autoload files
Class Twilio\TwiML\Voice\Echo_ located in ./vendor/twilio/sdk/src/Twilio/TwiML/Voice/Echo.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Tests\Browser\ActivityReportLink located in ./tests/Browser/ActivityReportLinkTest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Tests\Browser\UserSettingsTest located in ./tests/Browser/TestUserSettings.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Sofa\Eloquence\Searchable\Searchable located in ./vendor/sofa/eloquence-base/src/Contracts/Searchable/Searchable.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Http\Controllers\EmailController located in ./app/Http/Controllers/Admin/EmailController.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Http\Requests\Admin\UpdateEventOfferRequest located in ./app/Http/Requests/Admin/UpdateEventofferRequest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover
```

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting your vendor folder then run:

```
composer clear-cache
composer install
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried your suggestion but the error still persists. I continue to experience the same problem.

Comment: Are you using composer v2?

Comment: Yes, I am running version 2.1.6

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What makes you think that clearing the cache should help?